# Calculate $\pi_{n}$ probability distribution

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

For this transition matrix P ,I have to find the probability distribution $\mathbb{P}(X_{n}=X)=\pi_{n}$ , with $X=\left\{1,2,3,4\right\}$

\begin{bmatrix}
    0       & 1/6 & 1/12 & 3/4 \\
    1/2       & 0 & 1/4 & 1/4  \\
    0 & 1/2 & 0 &1/2 \\
   1/2       & 1/3 & 1/6 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}

My idea is to calculate $\pi_{n}=\pi_{0}P^{n}$, but tried few times diagonalization and I didn't find any eigenvalue equal to 1 so I assume that diagonalization doesn't work for this matrix.Also I calculated $P^{2},P^{3}$ and there is no pattern in order to find $P^{n}$.

Is there any other method or idea in order to calculate $\pi_{n}$ , any advice would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct; the matrix cannot be diagonalized since it does not have a full set of eigenvectors, however you can put it into [Jordan normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form). Unfortunately for this matrix, it's not particularly pretty:

$$ S = \begin{bmatrix}
    -2 & -10 & 3 & 1 \\
    4 & 46 & -1 & 1 \\
    -5 & -56 & -7 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$ S^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
    -10/27 & -4/27 & -1/18 & 31/54 \\
    1/36 & 1/36 & 0 & -1/18 \\
    1/12 & -1/12 & 1/12 & -1/12 \\
31/108 & 25/108 & 5/36 & 37/108
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$ J = \begin{bmatrix}
    -1/2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1/2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

where

$$ P = SJS^{-1}$$

Which gives you an expression for $P^n$:

$$ P^n = S \begin{bmatrix}
    (-1/2)^n & n(-1)^{n+1} 2^{1-n} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & (-1/2)^n & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
  \end{bmatrix} S^{-1}
$$

So given some starting distribution $\pi_0$, you can calculate the distribution of $\pi_n$ via $\pi_n = \pi_0 P^n$.

Comment: Thank you very much.Yes yes the matrix is correct .Also I was thinking to change rows in order to avoid zeros in diagonal and then do diagonalization is this a correct way ?? Because I searched it on internet and I found nothing

Comment: @R.Karagiannhs Unfortunately not. A $n$x$n$ real matrix $P$ is diagonalizable if and only if the eigenvectors of $P$ form a basis of $\mathbb R^n$. But elementary row operations do _not_ affect the number of eigenvalues (or their multiplicities) of a matrix.

Comment: Elementary row operations **do** change eigenvalues. E.g., $\tiny{\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}}$ is obtained from the identity via a row swap, picking up $-1$ as an eigenvalue in the process. To preserve the eigenvalues, you’d have to permute *both* rows and columns, but that just keeps the zero on the diagonal. Similarly, $\tiny{\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}}$ can be obtained from the identity via row operations, but it doesn’t have any real eigenvalues or eigenvectors.

Comment: @amd Indeed, though I did specifically say the _number_ of eigenvalues. You can consider the identity to have two eigenvalues, $1$ and $1$. You have however demonstrated my remark about multiplicities is false. Perhaps it would be more correct to say that EROs do not affect the dimension of the span of the eigenvectors of a matrix?

Comment: Re: the number of eigenvalues—that’s seems tautological, since *every* complex $n\times\n$ matrix has $n$ eigenvalues in that sense. As to the effect of EROs, that doesn’t really work, either: in my first example, there are two eigenspaces instead of one after the row swap. Perhaps you meant *conjugation* by an elementary matrix (or any other nonsingular matrix, for that matter). That does leave eigenvalues intact.

Comment: @amd I'm trying to explain why you cannot simply row reduce to make a non-diagonalizable matrix diagonalizable.

Comment: The thing is, it *can* make a non-diagonalizable matrix diagonalizable: every nonsingular matrix row-reduces to the identity. However, the result isn’t similar to the original matrix and the eigenvalues are changed in the process. The key is that $Av=\lambda v$ doesn’t imply that $EAv=\lambda v$.